# Validation Rule To Detect Translated Picklist Values?

Tags: formula, case, validation, validation-rule

I am trying to create a Validation rule which will stop closing the case when either the Case Type or Subtype is blank. The formula which I have written -

```
AND(
  OR(ISBLANK(TEXT(Type__c)),
       ISBLANK(TEXT(Case_Subtype__c))
  ),
  ISCHANGED( Status ),
  OR( ISPICKVAL(Status,"Cancelled"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Completed"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Not Resolved"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Annulé€"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Terminé(e)"), 
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Non résolu(e)")
  )
)
```

With this one, Validation rule is working fine for **English** Users, but when a **French** user is trying to close the case by selecting any of the above Status, Validation rule is not working i.e. case is getting closed without providing Case Type and Subtype?

Translated Values for Case Status PickList values in French Language
[image]

Translated Values for Case Status PickList values in English Language
[image]

Comment: Validation rules (and Apex Code) *always* use the Master Label values, not translated values.  I'll need to do some research, but you might consider using the more direct `ISPICKVAL(Type__c,"")` instead of converting it via `TEXT`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Let me store the value in a variable and then go for string comparison. But your point makes sense to me. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

> Solution will be, In Translation Workbench for English language Case Status Picklist, define the translated values (same as picklist values), the way you have defined for French language.

And use master label and NOT the translated value in your validation.

```
AND(
  OR(ISBLANK(TEXT(Type__c)),
       ISBLANK(TEXT(Case_Subtype__c))
  ),
  ISCHANGED( Status ),
  OR( ISPICKVAL(Status,"Cancelled"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Completed"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,"Not Resolved")        
  )
)
```

> For the sake of **proof of concept** I have done this and it is working as expected.

Condition for validation rule provided:

`If Case status is completed, then Priority should be mandatory`

```
AND( 
   ISBLANK( TEXT(Priority) ) , 
   ISCHANGED( Status ), 
   OR( ISPICKVAL(Status,"Cancelled"), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status,"Completed") 
  ) 
)
```

Defined Case status in translation for English language as follows:

[image: English Translation]

Validation on Case is showing as follows:

[image: Validation on case english]

For French User, defined locale and language as follows:

[image: French user]

Defined the translation for French language:

[image: French translation]

Validation is perfectly working if Priority is blank when `Status = Terminé`

[image: Validation on French]

Comment: No this one is not working.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for English translation workbench as well. But still for French users it is not working.