# Validation Rule After Translate Picklist Values

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, translation

I have a validation rule like:
`AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,"CLOSED"),....)` and it worked but when I translated in Italian from "CLOSED" to "CHIUSO" the validation stop working. I thought the validations are based on master label picklist value. How can i fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Refer this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151064/validation-rule-to-detect-translated-picklist-values

Comment: this answer doesn't come whit a solution